# Group by in query taking last item in text column while aggregating int columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

Can someone please help me with aggregating the int columns and taking the col4 text value corresponding to the latest col2 date column.

Lets say we have the following table 'Table1':

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name | 2021-01-01 | 50 | First_Appearance |
| Name | 2021-01-02 | 60 | Second_Appearance |
| Name | 2021-01-04 | 40 | Third_Appearance |
| Place | 2021-01-01 | 50 | First_Appearance |
| Place | 2021-01-03 | 60 | Second_Appearance |
| Place | 2021-01-05 | 40 | Third_Appearance |
| Place | 2021-01-04 | 40 | Fourth_Appearance |

```
select name, max(col2), max(col3), max(col4)
from Table1
group by col1;
```

Above query will give me this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name | 2021-01-01 | 150 | First_Appearance |
| Place | 2021-01-05 | 190 | First_Appearance |

Can anyone help me with the query to get to the following table instead:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name | 2021-01-01 | 150 | Third_Appearance |
| Place | 2021-01-05 | 190 | Fourth_Appearance |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is conditional aggregation using `row_number()`:

```
select col1, max(col2), sum(col3),
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then col4 end) as col4
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2 desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by col1;
```

Comment: Thank you! it does the trick! Except that instead of sum, i have to use max. Sum is not compatible with nvarchar.

Comment: @python_enthusiast . . . Yes.  Fixed the answer.